# ¿Cómo realizar solicitud HTTP a un servidor en Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito hacer una petición HTTP a un servidor y no se completamente como hacerlo, sé que debo armar una url y pasarla junto algunos parámetros por método get o post no estoy seguro y no conozco el procedimiento completo.

Estoy usando este codigo pero me dice q excede el tiempo de espera?

```
try
            {
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[1000 * 1000 * 3];
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(query);
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "AWS_HS";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                return response.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception e) { return e.ToString(); }
```

Comment: Podrías usar el [API de Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_SearchingbyTitle.html).

Comment: Hola ...Tengo un Access Key Id  y un Secret Acces Key Id ....pero esto  ( Your_AssociateTag ) no se que significa ???

Comment: Para eso necesitas registrarte en el programa de Asociados http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/becomingAssociate.html

Comment: Llevas algún requerimiento especial que impida que utilices un `Task` con `HttpClient`?

Comment: La verdad soy nuevo en esto ...voy a editar mi pregunta y muestro el codigo que utilizo...

Comment: El error que te da no es por problemas de código, o el sitio al que le haces el request está muy lento o no te puedes conectar a el por la red

Comment: No creo yorodm por q escribo la URL  que envio en el navegador y me responde de una ....

Comment: estoy tratando de enviar esto http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ67SOPZRWPHPB47Q&AssociateTag=my053-20%20&Keywords=shoes&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2017-06-08T02%3A55%3A34.000Z

Answer (score 0):

Esta forma me funciono ya q el servidor AWS devuelve un archivo XML

```
public XmlTextReader ResponseWeb()
{
    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create("http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ67SOPZRWPHPB47Q&AssociateTag=my053-20&Keywords=shoes&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2017-06-09T02%3A07%3A54.000Z&Signature=a4cwN5gaMXzKNwF4XssjdOFsXbkLCp9ZtGWG%2BY5AIYc%3D");
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    return reader;
}
```